# Angular unit test failed HttpClient requests

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test a service I have that is responsable to do http calls. I could test for a success request, but I'm not able to make the tests when the status code of the response is different from 200.

For example, let's say the request return a 404 status, then I'm not able to test it properly.

This is my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(
        private _http: HttpClient,
        private _router: Router,
        private _toast: ToastsManager,
        private _auth: AuthService,
    ) { }

    public apiGet(url: string) {
        return this._http
            .get(url)
            .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
    }

    private handleError(error) {
        if (error.status === 401) {
            this._auth.logout();
            return Observable.throw(error);
        }

        if (error.status === 404) {
            this._router.navigateByUrl('not-found');
            return Observable.throw(error);
        }

        if (error.error && error.error.message) {
            this._toast.error(error.error.message);
        } else {
            this._toast.error('Something went wrong');
        }

        return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm testing:

```
describe('ApiService', () => {
    let service: ApiService;
    let backend: HttpTestingController;

    const mockSuccessResponse = { value: '123', name: 'John' };
    const mockSuccessStatus = { status: 200, statusText: 'Ok' };

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                MockModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule,
            ],
            providers: [
                ApiService,
            ]
        });

        service = TestBed.get(ApiService);
        backend = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    });

    it('should call the apiGet() function with success', () => {
        service.apiGet('mock/get/url').subscribe(response => {
            expect(response).toEqual(mockSuccessResponse);
        });

        const req = backend.expectOne('mock/get/url');

        expect(req.request.url).toBe('mock/get/url');
        expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');

        req.flush(mockSuccessResponse, mockSuccessStatus);
    });

    it('should execute handleError function on status different of 200', () => {
        service.apiGet('mock/error/url').subscribe(response => { }, error => {
            // Handle the error cases here (?)
        });

        const req = backend.expectOne('mock/error/url');

        req.flush(null, { status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found' });
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        backend.verify();
    });
});
```

I don't know how to continue from here. If I try to do something like `expect(service.handleError()).toHaveBeenCalled();` I'll get errors like `handleError is a private method`.

I also need to test if the function `logout()` on the `authService` will be called or if the route change to `not-found` on 404 errors.

What should I do to be able to test those cases, where the status of the response is different from 200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solve this issue was to test if the handleError function is called and then create another set of tests to test the handleError function alone.

```
it('should execute handleError function on status different of 200', () => {
    // "as any" to avoid the "private method" type errors
    spyOn(service as any, 'handleError');

    service.apiGet('mock/get/url').subscribe(() => { }, error => {
        // This is where I just check if the function was called
        // It also needs to be service['handleError'] to avoid type errors on private method
        expect(service['handleError']).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    const req = backend.expectOne('mock/get/url');

    req.flush(null, { status: 400, statusText: 'Error' });
});
```

Then I create another set of tests where I manually set the error code I'm trying to test, 404 for example:

```
it('should navigate to route "not-found" on status 404', () => {
    spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');

    const mockError = {
        status: 404,
        error: {
            message: 'Page not found',
        },
    };

    service['handleError'](mockError);

    // Here we adapt to test whatever condition it is
    // Mine is a simple redirect to an error page
    expect(router.navigateByUrl).toHaveBeenCalledWith('not-found');
});
```